# Synchronize database with active directory using unboundID LDAP

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, synchronization

I want to synchronize my database to active directory for password changes using unboundID LDAP.
I am very new to this.Can anyone help me Please!

Answer (score 3):

[UnboundID Synchronization Server](https://www.unboundid.com/products/synchronization-server.php) comes with a small native DLL called UnboundID Password Synchronization Agent for Active Directory to account for the fact that it cannot be done solely over LDAP.
Check out the UnboundID Synchronization Server Administration Guide, starting page 8 for a high-level description of the steps to take to Synchronize your Active Directory with another database, be it LDAP or relational. Then delve in the detailed procedure on page 110 in the section titled "Configuring Active Directory Synchronization" and be sure to verify that you are running AD on one of supported AD platforms (2003, 2003R2, 2008, 2008)

hope this helps
-arno

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to obtain the password from AD using LDAP.

You will need to do a password filter on every domain controller.
The operation is [described on this WIKI](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20and%20Passwords)

-jim